# DRF does not reverse Django url pattern: NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There is a complex app (not possible to just paste the code). Going to try to explain.

## Django

There is a `urls.py` file from the native Django app. The `urlpatterns` defines and register its urls. The `^foo/` defines a group of related urls and the `foonamepsace`.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       ...
                       url(r'^foo/', include('foo.urls', namespace='foonamespace')),
                       ...
```

Now there is a method `generate_report` which does some logic inside and then uses `render_to_string` to return the HTML:

```
def generate_report(..):
    ...
    return render_to_string('foo/foo_report.html', args)
```

**Everything works inside the app, the url get reversed successfully.**

## Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Now there is a DRF implementation and one of its resources is supposed to return a report in a binary format.

```
class PDFReportViewSet(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (BinaryFileRenderer, )

    def get(..):
        ...
        pdf = generate_report()  # <-- fails with NoReverseMatch
        ...
        return response
```

### Problem

The `ViewSet` calls the `generate_report`, however one gets an error when trying to parse the HTML:

> NoReverseMatch: foonamespace' is not a registered namespace

## Question

Any clues why DRF cannot reverse the namespcae/url from the the core of Django app? How to make sure DRF can reverse a namespace from the core `urls.py` `urlpattern`?

### Added

After investigation, inside the `foo_report.html` any usage of the url, for example `{% url 'foonamespace:123' %}` or `{% url 'barnamespace:123' %}` produces the error - **only if ran from the DRF** (running the same page using native Django works fine).

### URLS

**foo.urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from foo.views import (FooListView, FooDetailView...)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', FooListView.as_view(), name='foo_list'),
                       url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', FooDetailView.as_view(), name='foo_details'),
```

---

Important note. The app is served at *some.domain.com/*, while the REST is served from *some.domain.com/rest*. So may be this way `/rest` just don't include anything because it is a parent of the root (which includes the `foo.urls.py`)

Comment: where's the code of the actual reverse() call? Is it in your template? Can you show it?

Comment: There is no reverse call. The core code calls (reverses) the HTML files inside `render_to_string` like: `return render_to_string('foo/foo_report.html', args)`. When core calls `generate_report` it works. When DRF calls the same `generate_report` - NoReverseMatch. **NOTE:** then `generate_report` is located inside `models.py` file.

Comment: there's no `{% url %}` in the template `foo_report.html`? It's not possible you get a `NoReverseMatch` error if there's not url to reverse.

Comment: Ok, you have pointed to the right direction. The issue was inside a `foo_report.html` file. I have just stripped it and left an empty HTML and all works! Currently investigating what is wrong inside the html-template file.

Comment: Updated the description, looks like DRF simply doesn't load the namespaces anywhere. Again, everything works fine once the same HTML page is called from the UI (not a REST).

Comment: show us `foo.urls.py`, do you declare `app_name` in it? Which version of Django and which version of DRF are you using?

Comment: No `app_name`. `foo.urls.py` pretty much import modules and defines a `urlpatterns` (which is then imported by the root `urls.py`. I have checked https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs and tried to add `app_name = 'foonamespace'`. However that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm, using Django 1.8.9. The `app_name` seems to only exist in 1.9.

Comment: In Django 1.8 you set the `app_name` attribute in the pattern itself, next to the `namespace` attribute. Note that `namespace` sets an instance namespace, whereas `app_name` sets the application namespace. There might be an incompatibility with DRF, seeing you're on such an old version of Django. DRF dropped support for Django 1.8 in version 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was managed to resolve my issue with the help from @dirkgroten. It was difficult to see the problem without looking at the source code.

## Solution

Updated the `routers.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = router.urls
urlpatterns += patterns('',
                        url(r'^foo/', include('foo.urls', namespace='foonamespace')),
                        )
```

### Explanation

Basically, the app was serve from the root url `/` while the rest was served from `/rest`. The DRF router simply didn't include any of the root routes. Adding them manually like it is shown in `solution` resolved the problem and made `foonamespace` visible for all DRF elements.